# Docker desktop mac wont update docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I updated docker desktop for Mac (intel) this morning to Docker Desktop 4.9.1. My docker compose version won't seem to update. When I run `docker-compose --version` in my terminal it returns `docker-compose version 1.25.5, build unknown`. I tried installing docker-compose with brew and after some tinkering I got confirmation that it installed version 2.6.0, however after restarting docker desktop and my computer, I still get 1.25.5 when I run `docker-compose --version`.

How can I force docker to use a newer version of docker-compose?

NOTE: In my docker-compose.yml file I have version 2 running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My docker compose also came via Docker Desktop on MacOS and it did not update/had the latest the latest version of docker-compose. I resolved this by installing docker-compose via brew:

https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/docker-compose

```
brew install docker-compose
```

Don't forget to follow the after-install instructions:

"Compose is now a Docker plugin. For Docker to find this plugin, symlink it:"

```
mkdir -p ~/.docker/cli-plugins
ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/docker-compose/bin/docker-compose ~/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to solve this was to completely manually uninstall docker desktop and all docker related items from brew. I deleted every docker file I could find from my lib and then reinstalled.